# A working generator function without "yield"

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

In Python 3.5 this returns a generator, but there is no *yield*:

```
def square(n):
    return (x**2 for x in range(n))

print(square) 
# <function square at 0x7f1ad0990f28>
print(square(10))
# <generator object square.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f1ad08e0af0>
```

Apart from being more apparently a generator function, is there a reason to prefer a *yield*'ed version, like

```
def square(n):
    for x in range(n): yield x**2

print(square)
# <function square at 0x7f1ac413ed90>
print(square(10))
# <generator object square at 0x7f1ad08e0d58>
```

To me they seem to work identically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is indeed not a generator, but this expression **is**:

```
(x**2 for x in range(n))
```

It is a *generator expression*, see the [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Both a generator expression and a function body containing `yield` result in a generator object. Since both are an *object*, you can pass it around and return one from a function.

A generator function and the equivalent generator expression are functionally exactly the same. They produce the same bytecode. Pick the one you feel is more readable for your use case.

Comment: That's it, now I realize what <genexpr> tried to tell me.